# Parallax Scrolling – How are these effects achieved on http://www.dangersoffracking.com/?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, parallax, jquery-scrollable

I'm not a big fan of parallax scrolling, mostly because it's not so mobile-friendly, but I am currently designing a home page where it would work really well.

On the http://www.dangersoffracking.com/ page, there are two effects that I particularly like: 1) the fading in and then disappearance of text boxes at certain times (can be observed at the beginning) 
[image: Text Box Fading in on scroll and then out when scrolling out]

2) on the top left hand side and then on the top right hand side the small icons with information seem to be added to a "menu" by scrolling through the page.

[image: Icon Menu on the Top right hand side]

I'm a bit of a novice at JavaScript/JQuery so would appreciate it if someone could explain in details how these work and maybe provide an example with JSFiddle? 
I feel like these could provide a useful resource for others too!

Thank you!

Comment: Best way to actually learn something: `Ctrl+U` and start reading the HTML, CSS and JS. The libraries used have the URL for their documentation. And the ones made by the front-end are quite easy to understand.

Comment: This might not be the best place for this type of question - this I think would be better on a tutorial-like site; correct me if I have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy happy to move it there, could you recommend one? I was more interested in the JQuery that makes those animations happen, than anything!

Comment: How about we discuss this in chat?